# Deleting specific rows within a matrix based on cell values - Matlab

Tags: arrays, matlab, matrix, rows

I gave this a search but could only find answers for when the row number is known.

I have a N by 4 matrix and am trying to remove rows based on the specific values in the second column and then the first column.

Initially I approached this the wrong way by filtering the matrix based on the values I didn't want, and then taking it away from the initial matrix, which obviously was not the result I wanted. (see below)

```
days = [669 680 298 299];
ind = ismember(B(:,2),days);
D = B(ind,:);
C=[B;-D];
```

I'm assuming there is a very similar way of removing rows, instead of filtering for them?
If you could help me in any way it would be much appreciated!

Edit:

Input:

```
 1002 101 04 92
 1002 12 12 298
 1002 298 12 589
 1002 680 12 589
```

Output:

```
 1002 101 04 92
 1002 12 12 298
```

I can't use row numbers as the matrix has millions of rows

Comment: Post a small example with input and desired output

Comment: What is your criteria?

Comment: Removing a row where the value in the second column is equal to a value listed in the 'days' array.

Comment: You mention filtering on the second column **and then the first column**.  Your code example does not filter along the first column.  Also, why can't you use the row numbers if this matrix already fits into memory?

Comment: I don't know all the row numbers for the data. The provided code is just an example, I didn't include my code for filtering the first column, as it would require an almost identical function to the second column.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To remove rows based on second column:

```
B(ismember(B(:,2),days),:) =  [];
```

or equivalently

```
B = B(~ismember(B(:,2),days),:);
```

Or, in your code, change third and fourth lines into

```
C = B(~ind,:);
```

Comment: Ah brilliant! I knew I was almost there!